# Are virtual methods for methods that are not created until runtime?

Tags: c++, methods, runtime, virtual

I have had a bit of trouble understanding the purpose of a virtual method in C++. Does a method have to be virtual if its object is not created at compile time? For example, if you had to pick a farm animal during run time, all of the animal's methods would need to be virtual because until the user picks one you don't know if it will be created or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C"? C++ doesn't have "methods"; they're called "member functions". A member function doesn't have "its object". A Good Book would probably be a fine start to learn about C++.

Comment: You can't create methods at runtime (in C++, that is) and you can't create objects at runtime (except for some exotic definition of "object" that includes template instanciations or something like that).

Comment: @delnan: What does `new MyClass();` do if it doesn't create an object at runtime? Templates are not instantiated at runtime, they are basically compile-time code generators.

Comment: @Kleist: Yes, of course. A typo on my side, I meant to write "compile time" - I was referring to: "Does a method have to be virtual if its object is not created at compile time?"

Answer (score 7):

No, that's completely incorrect. A method has to be virtual if the method needs to be selected based on the object's *type* and the *type* isn't known at compile time. If your code looks like this:

```
Animal *x;
if(y==2)
{
    x = new Animal();
    x->DoSomething();
}
```

The compiler knows at run time that `x`'s type is 'Animal'. So it knows which version of 'DoSomething' to call. But look at this code:

```
Animal *x;
if(y==1) x=new Zebra();
else if (y==2) x=GetSomeAnimal();
else x=new Giraffe();
x->DoSomething();
```

Here, `x`'s type is not known at compile time. It could be a Zebra, it could be a Giraffe, or it could be any type of Animal that the `GetSomeAnimal` function returns. There is no way to know whether the call of `DoSomething` should call `Zebra::DoSomething`, `Giraffe::DoSomething` or something else entirely. So `Animal::DoSomething` needs to be virtual.

And just to show it has nothing to do with what will be created, consider this:

```
void MyFunction(Animal &x)
{
    x.DoSomething();
}

void MyOtherFunction(int x)
{
   Giraffe g;
   Zebra z;
   if(x==2) MyFunction(g);
      else MyFunction(f);
}
```

Here it's perfectly clear that one `Giraffe` and one `Zebra` will be created. But if `Animal::DoSomething` is not virtual, `MyFunction` will call `Animal::DoSomething` both times rather than `Giraffe::DoSomething` on the Giraffe and `Zebra::DoSomething` on the Zebra. (Of course, if that's what you *want*, don't make the method virtual.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `x->DoSomething()` is a virtual call even if `x` is always of the same type and that's provable at compiletime. The compiler may optimize it, but that shouldn't matter when explaining the concept to a beginner.

Comment: I think my message was unclear, I did not mean if the Animal will be created or not, but rather if one of the sub-animals will be created or not. And isn't -> used when dealing with pointers to objects?

Comment: @delnan I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say. We're talking about whether the method has to be virtual or not. In the first case, the method does not have to be virtual. In the second case, if it is not virtual, *bad* things will happen. (Assuming the intention was that the type-specific version of `DoSomething` be called.)

Comment: @SaxSalute In this case, `x` is a pointer to an `Animal`. The same thing can happen with references. The issue is not with what is created but with what `x` may point to. At compile time, there's no way to know what type of Animal `x` will point to at run time, and the same code may point to one type of animal at one time and another at another time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If the first example is for a non-`virtual` `DoSomething`, your answer makes more sense. I hadn't considered that at all because (1) having pointers wouldn't have any other benefit in such a snippet and (2) your explanation of that snippets talks about runtime types. Excuse my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the purpose of virtual methods [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Purpose). I'd also recommend you take a look at ["Object Oriented Programming in ANSI C"](http://silversoft.net/docs/ooc.pdf) book.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `virtual` is the thing built into C++ to support [OOD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) polymorphism (specifically the [run-time or dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) one).

When you want different objects of same type (`Animal`) to behave differently (`getProduceName()` returns "pork" or "beef" or "egg" or ...) depending on context (whether `Animal` is actually `Pig` or `Cow` or `Chicken` or ...) you make that behavior/function `virtual`.

Usually a good OOD would have good interface/implementation separation. This, in C++, is realized using inheritance along with `abstract` classes/methods.

So actually when you make `getProduceName()` polymorphic/`virtual` you are actually trying to extract the interface (`Animal`) out of different implementations (`Pig` or `Cow` or `Chicken` or ...) to shield your client code from different implementations. This way if you have to support a new implementation, you don't have to change the client code as long as it adheres to the interface `Animal`.

**So to answer the question:** *Does a method have to be virtual if its object is not created at compile time?*

Whether the method is virtual or not doesn't depend on when the object is created (compile/run-time).  It depends on how you wish to design your application. Making a function `virtual` helps you in extracting interface out of different implementations. If certain function (`getOwnerName()`) has same implementation across all implementing classes (`{return ownerName;}`) then it needn't be made virtual.

PS: IMHO polymorphism is a side product of a good OOD, you don't design your classes to implement "runtime polymorphism", then exhibit runtime polymorphism when you have a good OO design.

Answer (score 0):

One of the grander purposes of virtual functions is to **allow old code to call new code**.

Consider this. A function takes as a parameter a Car object. Suppose it does things like test_drive(), refuel(), calculate_ability(), getStoppingDistance(), etc. All these methods depend on what car type you pass in.

But new cars come out every year. Now, in the real world, we would just import an XML file that contained the properties that make up all the cars. But suppose for the sake of argument we had to do this statically: Every time we found out about new cars, we'd have to rebuild our entire program. If our program was huge, this would be very inconvenient. In a way, we are calling the same functions,  - but in a way we're not - since the object's type varies. Why should we have to recompile ?

Virtual functions to the rescue! When the car manufacturer releases a new car, they concurrently release a header file declaring the new type ( which inherits from a common base class with virtual functions ), and a library ( object files that define the specific methods ). So instead of recompiling our application, we just relink to this new library. Thus, old code ( our app ) is able to call new code ( the new library that comes with the car ).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this code:

```
Animal * a = new Pig();
```

The pointer `a` has a *static type* of `Animal` and a *dynamic type* of `Pig`.

Now let's say we're calling

```
a->MakeASound();
```

If `MakeASound` is virtual then the `MakeASound` method of the dynamic type (`Pig`) is called.

If it is not, the `MakeASound` of the static type (`Animal`) is called, regardless whether `Pig` overwrites the `MakeASound` method or not.